# Proving properties of binary relations with existential quantifier

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

I'm taking a discrete mathematics course in my computer science studies and came across the following:

Given the relation:
$$R = \{(a, b)\in\Bbb Z\ \times\Bbb Z\ | \exists z\in\ \Bbb Z\ : a - b = z\cdot p \}$$

with $p\in \Bbb N_0\;$,

prove whether or not the relation is reflexive, symmetrical, antisymmetrical or transitive.

As I understand the question I only have to provide one z that satisfies this condition for each property. Assuming that is the case I found the following answers:

The relation is:

*reflexive*, since $z = 0$ satisfies $a - a = z \cdot p$

$^1$*symmetrical*, since $a-b = z \cdot p \implies b - a = z \cdot p$  is true for $z = 0$

*anti-symmetrical*, since $ a- b = z \cdot p \land b-a = z \cdot p \implies a = b$ is true for $z = 0$

*transitive*, since $a-b = z\cdot p \land b -c = z\cdot p\implies a = c$ is true for $z = 0$

However, I think I commit some very basic fallacies, because I completely ignore p. Additionally, if we assume that R is not transitive, would I have to prove it for every z?

Edit: Forgot to ask a question:

Are these answers correct and if not why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The set of evens is the set of integers such that there exists an integer $k$ such that $2k$. Your argument is analogous to saying the set of evens has the "all of them are squares" property because $4$ is a square.

Since there are evens other than the one ($4$) with $k=2$ and ordered pairs in the relation other than the ones with $z=0$, these arguments are generally invalid for general properties that say something holds for every two or three pairs in the relation (but reflexivity is okay); you were right to be suspicious.

For each property, you have to either show that it holds for all pairs in the relation or find a counterexample (which may only involve one or two $z$s). As a hint, your answers for some properties might depend on the value of $p$.

Comment: I deleted an earlier comment. Now $R$ is reflexive for any $z$ if $p = 0$ and for $z = 0$ if $p>0$, correct?

Comment: But since I only have to provide one $z$ for which the relation holds, it is sufficient enough to name $z = 0$. Am I correct in that assumption?

Comment: @Nadim, yes. Since you can get all $(a,a) $ by using $z=0$, you're correct.

Comment: Cool! Thank you very much. I got the following characteristics for $R$:
reflexiv, not symmetrical, anti-symmetrical and transitive

Comment: @Nadim' , I would check over your work. For instance, is $(0,p)$ in $R$? What about $(p,0)$? What does that tell you about the properties $R$ might have?

Comment: Since there exist $(0, p)$ and $(p, 0)$ in $R$ the relation is not anti-symmetric and not transitive, because $(0, 1)´, (1, 2), (0, 2)$ do not yield the same result. So $R$ is reflexive, not symmetric, not antisymmetric and not transitive.

Comment: @Nadim', You don't need those three to yield the same result for transitivity. Transitivity would just say (for example) that if $p$ is such that both $(0,1)$ and $(1,2)$ are in $R$ then so is $(0,2)$. Also, what counterexample to symmetry did you have in mind?

Comment: My original assumption was based on the idea that for any $(p, q)$ I have to find a $(q, p)$ so that $p - q = z \cdot p$ and $q - p = z \cdot p$:But going with your comment I only have to show that $aRb$ implies $bRa$ whcih is possible by naming different z. If that's the case, it explains why $R$ is not antisymmetric, since I have to find one $z$ for which $aRb$ and $bRa$ are both true.